# "Намного высокие чистые расходы"

Tags: лексика

Подскажите, правильно ли следующее выражение?

> В последней версии этого исследования, несмотря на то, что североамериканцы имеют *намного высокие чистые расходы,* чем европейские страны...

Comment: Что с этим надо сделать, в чем вопрос. В фраза грамматически неправильная или неправильно процитирована, это понятно. Ну а дальше-то что?

Comment: Такое впечатление, что это не русский язык, а английский.

Comment: Вы не могли бы привести всю фразу? Пока видно две ошибки: грубая и менее грубая. Но без окончания фразы трудно себе представить, что же "в последней версии" можно противопоставить глобальному сравнению расходов (может, ещё какая-то ошибка закралась).

Answer (score 1):

Фраза неправильна, это понятно.

Если по минимуму, править можно так:
*"В последней версии этого исследования, несмотря на то, что североамериканцы имеют чистые расходы намного выше, чем европейские страны..."*
Или так:
*"В последней версии этого исследования, несмотря на то, что североамериканцы имеют чистые расходы намного выше, чем европейские страны..."*
Второе лучше, но при этом в опущенной части должен быть глагол (показывается, доказавается или "[было] доказано").

А вообще фраза совершенно бездарная. "имеют расходы" - уже плохо. Плюс "несмотря на" явно не на месте, отделяет "исследование" от "показано", получается, что несмотря на то, что показано.

В идеале надо стремиться примерно к следующему.

*В последней версии этого исследования **показано, что**, несмотря на то что североамериканцы **несут** более высокие, чем европейские страны, чистые расходы [на выращивание жареных петухов], [европейские жареные петухи лучше поддаются дрессировке]* (нужное вписать).

Если не "несут", то осуществляют, производят - по контексту.

И на будущее: если нужна правка, пишите фразу целиком, даже предыдущая и последующая не помешают.

Comment: Несмотря на то, что у североамериканцев чистые расходы намного выше, чем в европейских странах... или несмотря на то, что чистые расходы североамериканцев намного выше, чем в европейских странах...  Интересно, что там дальше.

Answer (score 0):

Эта фраза неправильна, потому что если наречие модифицирует прилагательное, то прилагательное должно быть в форме сравнительной степени. Грамматично было бы сказать:

"В последней версии этого исследования, несмотря на то, что североамериканцы имеют намного более высокие чистые расходы, чем европейские страны...".

Comment: А где у вас сравнительная степень прилагательного?

Comment: "намного более высокие" - более высокие - аналитическая форма. Первый пример без наречия "намного", поэтому сравнительная степень не нужна

Comment: Если есть "чем'' должна быть и сравнительная степень в первой части.

Comment: Не обязательно в этом предложении. Это предложение вырвано из контекста (о чем нам говорит анафорическое местоимение этого в начале предложения), поэтому оно не обязательно должно содержать второй объект сравнения. Поэтому само предложение правильное.

Comment: А, я поняла, вы про вторую часть моего ответа? Да, действительно, учитывая "чем", так сказать нельзя. Исправлю, спасибо.

Comment: У вас: «Грамматично было бы сказать...» =========  Грамматично чем отличается от грамотно?

Answer (score 0):

Выражение неправильное. Наречие НАМНОГО лучше использовать с формой сравнительной степени прилагательного или наречия: *намного выше*, например.